# Can get('/', function (req, res){} can't be called server

Tags: node.js, express

I was working on fetching data from mysql and using it to create d3js graph on node.js. I learnt that server can only be made from modules 'http' and 'request'. If I am not using them and using

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
       //
    });
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('running server on port ' + port) 
});
```

They are solving the same purpose. 
What concept of server am I missing? What are the limitations of fetching data this way?

Comment: here `app` is you initiated from `express` if I am not mistaken, so it will initiate the server as you are asking, so no need of external module like http or request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) web framework :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})


let port=3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('running server on port ' + port) 
});
```

Comment: Okay Thanks Saurabh. Saurabh I was wanting to implement socket.io in same. Is there any different thing I'll have to do while following it's documentation.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/simple-chat-application-in-node-js-using-express-mongoose-and-socket-io-ee62d94f5804/